# How to iterate a Swift [AnyObject] array with a downcast?

Tags: arrays, swift, cocoa

How can I loop over an array of AnyObjects in Swift and downcast to the appropriate class at the same time? I can do it verbosely like this, but I just can't seem to find a way to do this without an "if let" inside the loop:

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, sortDescriptorsDidChange oldDescriptors: [AnyObject]) {
    var currentSort = tableView.sortDescriptors
    for s in currentSort {
        if let ss = s as? NSSortDescriptor {
            println("keyPath: \(ss.key()), ascending: \(ss.ascending)")
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to implement sorting for an array of custom objects which is the data source for an NSTableView.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the array of `[AnyObject]` is supposed to be *entirely* composed of the type you want, you can do a en-mass cast:

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, sortDescriptorsDidChange oldDescriptors: [AnyObject]) {
    let currentSort = tableView.sortDescriptors as? [NSSortDescriptor]
    for s in currentSort ?? [] {
        println("keyPath: \(s.key()), ascending: \(s.ascending)")
    }
}
```

This uses `[]` to substitute an empty array for the `nil` you get if it turns out one or more of the `AnyObject` were not of the right type – you’d still need an `if…else` if you wanted explicit error handling rather than silent failure.

Alternatively if you want your program to trap in case of failure, you could use `as!` but then it’s a bit of a shame if you find this out in production.

By the way, if the fact that you have to come up with a new name for the unwrapped value was part of what was bothering you, you can just give it the same name:

```
let x: Int? = 1
if let x = x {
    println(x)
}
```

which declares a local unwrapped `x` which masks the outer `x` within the `if`.

If some but not all might be of the right type and you only want to operate on those, `mapSome` is a handy array extension to have around:

```
extension Array {
    func mapSome<U>(transform: T->U?) -> [U] {
        return lazy(self).map(transform)
            .filter { $0 != nil }
            .map { $0! }.array
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, sortDescriptorsDidChange oldDescriptors: [AnyObject]) {
    let currentSort = tableView.sortDescriptors.mapSome { $0 as? NSSortDescriptor }
    for s in currentSort {
        println("keyPath: \(s.key()), ascending: \(s.ascending)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That about covers it. A VERY thorough answer indeed!